# Connecting to open-ssh-server fails after Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, ubuntu-14.04

I updated Ubuntu from version 12.04 to 14.04.Now, I cannot connect via ssh from remote machines to my ubuntu box. The error message is 'connect to host 131.188.209.xx port 22: No route to host'. All went fine before upgrading.

My first suspicion was that my box is not listening to relevant ports, here 22, so I typed :

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       4237/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7072            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1181/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/perl       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1546/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8085            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168/perl       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3062/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      4237/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1218/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3062/sshd
```

Second, my apache did not work on the IP 131.188.209.xx either, so maybe there is a firewall activated by default on Ubuntu 14.04 so I installed gufw and startet it. The result was that the firewall is deactivated.

How can I solve this issue - where can I find relevant information?